# Chemmacros breaks auto-pst-pdf

Tags: pdftex, eps, includegraphics, chemmacros, chemnum

this is my first time here but I will try to do my best. My document stopped compiling and I was able to boil it down to the following MWE.
Basically I need `chemnum` (and therefore `auto-pst-pdf`) to replace temporary markers in my chemical schemes (all `.eps` files).
Chemmacros seems to break this because if I comment it out, the document compiles just fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

Hello World...

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{picture.eps}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{picture2.png}
    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

From the log:

```
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of 00_preamble-autopp.dvi failed.
This warning occured on input line 128.


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Could not create 00_preamble-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
This warning occured on input line 128.

-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
```

I think it has something to do with ghostscript or related. This was tested on a fresh install on Xubuntu.
I can supply log files of a failed and of a working compilation. If anything is needed, please tell me and I will try to provide.

Best regards,
Phil

PS: I was able to reproduce the error with these files:

1. [File 1](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/SARS-CoV-2_without_background.png)
2. [File 2](https://de.freepik.com/download/6096724)

Comment: I know what happens, but need to think about how this should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2020-10-10:** A new pst-pdf is on the way to ctan which should resolve the issue.

The problem is that `pst-pdf` loads the graphics driver `pdftex.def` in *dvi* mode. But `pdftex.def` is is meant for pdflatex in *pdf* mode. Until now this didn't harm, but the last update added code to `pdftex.def` to improve the page color handling and this code doesn't work in dvi mode. The new code is not executed in all cases, but for example if pgf is loaded  (as done by chemmacros), then its execution is triggered and the latex compilation in auto-pst-pdf fails.

Imho the best would be if `pst-pdf` wouldn't load `pdftex.def` and I opened an issue about it https://github.com/rolfn/pst-pdf/issues/5. If `pst-pdf` can not be adapted `pdftex.def` will probably need some addition to guard against this use.

Until then it should work if you define the missing conditional in your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifGPT@pagecolor
\makeatother
```

**Warning** If you have a new latex (2020-10-01) ensure that you have also `auto-pst-pdf` version `2020/10/08 v0.7` as the previous version had a bug. If you have an older version, use the option `cleanup=` to prevent it from cleaning up files.